# sql select relevant events by connections in 4 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join rows from 1 table "event" AND influence the result by connections in 3 other tables: user_follower,user_sport AND user_group

This is my query, which doesn't return anything:

```
SELECT e.* FROM event e
    JOIN user_sport us ON e.sport_id = us.sport_id
    JOIN user_follower uf ON uf.user_id = e.user_id
    JOIN user_group ug ON e.group_id = ug.group_id
    WHERE us.user_id=1 AND uf.follower_id=1 AND ug.user_id=1
    AND e.id_event NOT IN(SELECT event_id FROM user_event WHERE user_id=1)
    ORDER BY e.timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,5
```

Table structure goes like this:

```
event        user_follower            user_group           user_sport
id_event     user_id (who's followed) user_id              user_id
user_id      follower_id              group_id             sport_id
group_id
sport_id
....
```

Basically I'm trying to select all events that are relevant to user with ID 1. Which are events made by people he is following or by group he is a member of or that are related to his favourite sports.

Does anybody know how to do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First, are you SURE that "no result" is not the right answer with your query? Using JOIN, each part of the query "filter" the result. So maybe getting "nothing" is the right result?

Comment: There could be many reasons this doens't return anything. Try replacing all the `join` with `left join` to see if any of the other tables might be null, remember doing just a `join` will only return a value if it exists in both tables.

Comment: Yep, it returned 0 rows and the filter wasn't supposed to do that, anyway I found my awnser below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it via multiple inner queries:

```
select * from event
where user_id in (
 select user_id from user_follower where follower_id = 1
)
or group_id in (
 select group_id from user_group where user_id - 1
)
or sport_id in(
 select sport_id from user_sport where user_id = 1
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an INNER JOIN (JOIN defaults to INNER), which means that only rows that meet the criteria in all the joined tables will be returned. If you want the rows from event regardless of whether or not rows exist in the joined tables then you need to use a LEFT JOIN (which is an outer join). Then you'll also need to move the criteria that refer to the outer joined tables from the WHERE clause to the ON clauses for the joins because the WHERE clause is applied after the joins and for event rows where no joined rows are found the joined table columns are going to be NULL.

The query will be something like

```
SELECT e.* FROM event e
LEFT JOIN user_sport us ON e.sport_id = us.sport_id
LEFT JOIN user_follower uf ON uf.user_id = e.user_id AND uf.follower_id=1
LEFT JOIN user_group ug ON e.group_id = ug.group_id
WHERE us.user_id=1
AND e.id_event NOT IN(SELECT event_id FROM user_event WHERE user_id=1)
ORDER BY e.timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,5
```